# Stripe "Missing required param: line_items[0][currency]." Node js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm creating subscription on node js backend. It had been working good but today I got this error. I didn't made any changes in code - it just starts returning this error.
backend code:

```
 app.post('/api/subscription', async (req, res) => {
  const { priceId } = req.body;
  
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: "subscription",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
      // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
      // is redirected to the success page.

      success_url: 'https://someurl',
      cancel_url: 'https://someurl',
    });

    res.send({
      sessionId: session.id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400);
    return res.send({
      error: {
        message: e.message,
      }
    });
  }
})
```

from client I'm sending

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/subscription", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ priceId }),
    });
```

I've taken this code from official stripe example here https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout
And as I said it works fine, and now I've tested it on two different stripe accounts and getting the same error. It looks like something changed on stripe but not in their documentation

Comment: It seems that a currency parameter is required in line_items, have you tried that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `priceId` is `undefined`/`null` it won't be sent in the request.  If the Price isn't present the API assumes you're trying to specify information about a line item without using a Price, and one of the first checks it performs is for a valid `currency` (which you don't have), which results in the  `Missing required param: line_items[0][currency].` error.

To fix the issue you'll need to figure out why `priceId` isn't being populated as expected, and you may also want to add a check to make sure `priceId` is valid before proceeding to the Checkout Session creation step.

Comment: thanks! it works. priceId was undefined - there is some issue with bodyparser

Comment: Awesome!  Can you accept this answer as the one that solved the issue so others know this is the right solution?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new on stackoverflow. To make it I have to check a check mark below counter  in left top corner? If it didn't accepted now let me know, please

Comment: Yep, that worked, thank you and welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Comment: Great answer, it helped me in rails (I wasn't passing the price_id from the form to the controller correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is struggling - when adding the document, make sure you use "price: XXX" and not "priceId: XXX", as seen in some tutorials. It was giving me the missing currency error.